# ACS namespace, Issuer Name, Issuer Key for the locally hosted BizTalk Adapter Service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, biztalk

I am trying to insert a flat file data in to Sql table using BizTalk service and vs2012. For that I have installed the  Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services SDK in my local machine. The SDK created the BizTalk service template in my visual studio 2012 and also the BizTalk adapter WCF service in my local IIS (because I mentioned the server as http://localhost in the installation process). I added the BizTalk adapter service in to VS Server Explorer using the SDK generated BizTalk adapter WCF service url which resides in my local IIS (http://localhost:8080/BAService/ManagementService.svc/).

The issue now I am facing is when I try to expand the newly created BizTalk Adapter Service to create the SQL Server LOBTarget it is asking for the ACS Namespace,  Issuer Name, Issuer Secret, so I am not able to create the SQL LOB Target.

What values should I give here, If I have ACS namespace, issuer name and issuer secret in azure portal can I give that here, will that work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the ACS namespace, issuer name, and issuer secret from the Azure Portal.

I wrote a couple blogs on how to do this a while back: https://blog.tallan.com/2014/11/10/mabs-eai-bridge-lob-lookup-part-1-of-2/ and https://blog.tallan.com/2014/12/05/mabs-eai-bridge-lob-lookup-part-2-of-2/

The relevant portion is:

> You’ll need the ACS Information for your newly created service for several of the following steps.  You can get this information by selecting the service you created and clicking “Connection Information” at the bottom.  That will display the following information.  You’ll need similar information for the ServiceBus relay (created in step 4) as well; I found it convenient to copy this information into an Excel sheet for quick reference during development (however, be sure this is stored in a secure manner and is consistent with your IT security policies – this is sensitive information that should not be disclosed to non-administrators of the service):[image]

Comment: You do need to host it in IIS on the machine that has the LoB system.  So if you want to connect to SQL Server on your company's intranet, it has to be hosted on a machine that has access to that SQL Server instance.  It will then create a secure endpoint that can be connected to from BizTalk services in the cloud.

Comment: Dan, will the Biztalk adapter service create automatically in the azure when we create the BizTalk Service in azure(like https://biztalkserviceurl:8080/BAService/ManagementService.svc/)? When I deploy the biztalk service to the cloud what should be the biztalk adapter service url instead of the localhost one? Do I need to host the biztalk adapter service  some where on the IIS (VM) manually?

Comment: Check the blog posts I posted..  It's all in there.